# CSS - Placeholder style not applying if selectors area combined

Tags: css, google-chrome, vendor-prefix

Why does this work in Chrome:

```css
.amsearch-input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<input class="amsearch-input" placeholder="It works!" />
```

...but this doesn't:

```css
.amsearch-input::-webkit-input-placeholder,
.amsearch-input::-moz-placeholder,
.amsearch-input::-ms-placeholder,
.amsearch-input::placeholder {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<input class="amsearch-input" placeholder="It fails! :(" />
```

Comment: `::-ms-placeholder` is breaking the rule. It's not the answer on why it's happening but usually it's because when a single selector fails the whole rule doesn't count. Needless to say the solution would be having separate rules each with its own selector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's common error when trying to deal with selectors containing vendor prefixes.

The issue here is that

> If there is an invalid pseudo-element or pseudo-class within in a chain or group of selectors, the whole selector list is invalid.

Source: [developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Webkit_Extensions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Webkit_Extensions#sect5)

There is also an article on css-tricks which you can read to get more context about this [One Invalid Pseudo Selector Equals an Entire Ignored Selector](https://css-tricks.com/one-invalid-pseudo-selector-equals-an-entire-ignored-selector/)

To fix it and make your code more sustainable you need to separate your rules like this:

```css
.amsearch-input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: red;
}
.amsearch-input::-moz-placeholder {
    color: red;
}
.amsearch-input::-ms-placeholder {
    color: red;
}
.amsearch-input::placeholder {
    color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

because `::-moz-placeholder` or `::-ms-placeholder` aren't a valid selector on chrome and chrome stop applying this styles.

```css
.amsearch-input::-webkit-input-placeholder,
.amsearch-input::placeholder {
    color: red;
}

.amsearch-input::-moz-placeholder,
.amsearch-input::placeholder {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<input class="amsearch-input" placeholder="It fails! :(" />
```